# Do we need a smart contract to implement bidding in NFT Marketplace? If yes do anyone have sample smart contracts to implement the same?

Tags: solidity, nft, auctions

could you please provide solidity smart contracts and links related to the same?
I would like to implement the bidding and auction functionalities for NFT marketplace platform.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/solidity-by-example.html#blind-auction) is an example of auction in official Solidity documentation.M Decentraland also has an extended bidding contract for ERC721 you can access [here](https://github.com/decentraland/bid-contract).